# Table not retaining columns

Tags: r, csv, shiny, dplyr

I can download my results table as a csv, however there are no columns. All the data is just in one column so the usefulness of the download it lost. How can I keep the structure and headers in the download?

```
output$Table <- 
    renderTable(
      myData() %>% 
        mutate(searchmatch <- str_extract(DocumentText, paste0("([^\\s]+\\s){50}",input$SearchPhrase,"(\\s[^\\s]+){50}"))) %>%
        select(-AHEADER,-AHEADER)
    )

  output$DownloadResults<-downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){"queryresults.csv"},
    content = function(queryresults){
      write.csv(myData(),queryresults)
    }
  )
```

I have replaced my header names with AHEADER for posting purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `write.csv` use `write.table` and specify the `sep` argument.
Depending on your system you might need `sep = ","`, `sep = ";"` or even something else.

If you want you can also save the output as `xslx` using the `open.xlsx` package:
Just use

```
content  = function(file) {
      openxlsx::write.xlsx(myData(), file, creator = "Your_Name")
    }
```